# Manageable timers in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I'm looking for a way to create named timers in node that can be started, stopped/paused and have their intervals or functionality changed.

I am making an IRC bot that I want to have say certain general messages on a timer.

I have this `messages.js` setup with a handful of objects like so

```
module.exports = [
  {
    title: "donate",
    message: "If you would like to help the stream out, donate at https://www.twitchalerts.com/donate/matax91 . All donations go toward the stream!",
    interval: 1,
    active: true
  },
  ...
]
```

And in my `app.js` I have this setup

```
var Messages = require('./messages');
var activeMessages = [];
client.addListener('join', function(){
  for(var id in Messages){
    if(Messages[id].active){
      console.log('set interval');
      activeMessages[Messages[id].title] = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('sent message');
        client.say(config.channels[0], Messages[id].message);
      },(Messages[id].interval * 60000));
    }
  }
});
```

The problem I see is that it's going to be really hard to pause these messages, or make changes to their intervals if I want to. I feel like there is a module that may be able to help me do this, but my searches aren't turning up much. Any advice would be great!

Comment: You can have one cycle (`setInterval`) that shoots, say every minute, and goes through the list of messages and sends active ones based on the time when it should be sent next (also property of message). Thus you won't have a big number of timers (which impact overall server performance) and will be able to dynamically manage intervals and content just modifying properties of messages

Comment: You make a good point, that may be easier to work with. Thanks for the input!